# How to capture middleware exception from other middleware in Django

Tags: python, django

I coding backend system with Django now, and I want control all exception from Django, so I create one middleware which name is `CustomExceptoinMiddleware` to control exception.
But sometimes other middleware also raise exception, I hope CustomExceptoinMiddleware can capture it too, but I don't know how to do it.

Can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Python version: 3.7
Django version: 2.2.3

```py
Setting.py

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    "api.core.middleware.CustomExceptoinMiddleware ",
    "api.core.middleware.RaiseExcceptionMiddleware",
    ...
]
```

```py
# middleware.py

class CustomExceptoinMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        print(f"Capture exception: {type(exception)}")

class RaiseExcceptionMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        raise KeyError()
```

Comment: I think that problem is with the order od middlewares. Try make RaiseExcceptionMiddleware first mw.

Comment: I try all combination of order of middlewares, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that. As you may read in documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception) you can only catch exception from the view. More detailed:

> Again, middleware are run in reverse order during the response phase,
>   which includes process_exception. If an exception middleware returns a
>   response, the process_exception methods of the middleware classes
>   above that middleware won’t be called at all.